# Reverting the programmatically changed layout to the original xml file's settings

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the following code where in case1 it makes a field invisible and the remaining fields fill the screen however I want to revert it to the original xml layout once the case2 is in affect.

Here is my code;

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()) {

  case R.id.item1:
            singleView=true;
            doubleView=false;
            if(singleView && !doubleView){
            webView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            urlEditText2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            openUrl2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            webView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)); 
            }
            else{

            }

            //webView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100));
          return true;
  case R.id.item2:
            singleView = false;
            doubleView = true;
            webView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            urlEditText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            openUrl2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            urlEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.urlField);
            openUrl = findViewById(R.id.goButton);


          Toast.makeText(this, "Option2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 1 you can use `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE`.From [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

> View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
>
> View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for
>   layout purposes.

By using `View.GONE` your `WebView` and `EditText` don't take up any space while not visible, hence making a feel of non-existence.And in case 2 you can make it visible as you are doing currently.I don't think there are some other ways to revert the xml layout even though you have changed some views of it programmatically.